# Save data to local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to set a bush of variables in local storage but the function doesn't run, I've tried to get the value but without luck, How can I save fields in Local storage?

```
function setPerson(){
var person = { 'name': getElementById('name'), 'photo': getElementById('photo')};

// Put the object into the storage
    alert(person);
    localStorage.setItem('person', JSON.stringify(person));
};
```

**HTML**
 In the HTML I'm from fields put values into tags and they are populated, but when I try to fetch them and save them nothing is happening...

I also tried to out fixed values in there and then the alert is displayed, but then it only says object and not the value

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');
alert('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));;
```

Comment: Im calling to it in a other form and I can see that's its called

Comment: DONT use `alert` for debugging purposes, use `console`! You have a complex object, so `alert` will always say `[ObjectObject]`

Comment: ok, still wont recive it

Comment: if you want to use alert you should use '+' instead of ',':  alert('retrievedObject: '+ JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

Answer (score 28):

You can use localStorage like this:

```
// Retrieve your data from locaStorage
var saveData = JSON.parse(localStorage.saveData || null) || {};

// Store your data.
function saveStuff(obj) {
  saveData.obj = obj;
  // saveData.foo = foo;
  saveData.time = new Date().getTime();
  localStorage.saveData = JSON.stringify(saveData);
}

// Do something with your data.
function loadStuff() {
  return saveData.obj || "default";
}
```

**Update 2022:**
Since people still view this here's a more modern version. I like to wrap things like this in a service which gives you more control and type safety. You can easily add things like validation and errorhandling.

```js
class LocalStorageService {
  #keys = {
    persons: 'persons',
  };

  constructor() {
    this.storage = window.localStorage;
  }

  addPerson(person) {
    const persons = this.getPersons();
    persons.push(person);
    this.setPersons(persons);
  }

  getPersons() {
    return JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem(this.#keys.persons)) || [];
  }

  getPerson(id) {
    const persons = this.getPersons();
    return persons.find((person) => person.id === id);
  }

  setPersons(persons) {
    this.storage.setItem(this.#keys.persons, JSON.stringify(persons));
  }

  removePerson(person) {
    const persons = this.getPersons();
    const index = persons.indexOf(person);
    persons.splice(index, 1);
    this.setPersons(persons);
  }

  clear() {
    this.storage.clear();
  }
}

const storageService = new LocalStorageService();
const person = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'John',
  age: '20',
};

storageService.addPerson(person);

const persons = storageService.getPersons();
console.log(persons);
```

**[Web Storage API - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)**

Comment: Love how easy the localStorage is to use.

Answer (score 6):

First, you should use `console` instead of `alert`.

And, if you want to use the retrieved object somewhere, you'd better store it in a variable:

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));
console.log('retrievedObject: ', retrievedObject);
```

Comment: I believe the OP meant between sessions.

Answer (score 2):

W3C Schools gives you detailed examples on how to work with html and local storage.

[w3cSchools - Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getElementById` returns an HTML element, which is an object.

Then, `JSON.stringify` will attempt to iterate its own properties.

But probably, they haven't any (unless you added them manually).

Since you say they are fields, you can try saving its `value` instead:

```
var person = {
    name: document.getElementById('name').value,
    photo: document.getElementById('photo').value
};
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementById should be changed to

```
    document.getElementById
```

Also this will get you the entire DOM element. I assume you want what's inside the tag so i would say use

```
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML
```

instead.
Just referencing the DOM element will give you a circular strucure error when you attempt to stringify it.

Sample code that i have confirmed works:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="name">Hello</p>
<p id="photo">photo</p>
<script>

function setPerson(){
var person = { 'name': document.getElementById('name').innerHTML, 'photo':    document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML};

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('person', JSON.stringify(person));
}
setPerson()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```