# How can I store an input value in web local storege using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input like below.
I want to keep its value after the page is refreshed.
notice that I have the name attribute, not class or ID.

```
<input type="text" name="name" onkeyup="saveValue(event)"/> 
<input type="text" name="age" onkeyup="saveValue(event)"/>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nameArr = ["name"];
nameArr.forEach(function(el){
  document.getElementsByName(el)[0].value = getSavedValue(el);  
})

function saveValue(e) {
  var name = e.target.name;
  var val = e.target.value;
  localStorage.setItem(name, val);
}

function getSavedValue(v) {
  if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
    return "";
  }
  return localStorage.getItem(v);
}
</script>
```

it only works for 1 input.I want something that works on unlimited number of inputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save data to local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743862/save-data-to-local-storage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change parameter of `saveValue` to `event`:

`<input type="text" name="name" onkeyup="saveValue(event)"/>`

Since there are many elements with different names, maintain an array:

```
var nameArr = ["name"]; // Add more elements here
nameArr.forEach(function(el){
  document.getElementsByName(el)[0].value = getSavedValue(el);  
})
```

Inside `saveValue` use `e.target`, instead of `e`

```
var name = e.target.name;
var val = e.target.value;
```

These should get the code working. Here's a working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anuragsr/pen/wbjxOM)

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByName("name") returns an array.
if you are sure that there is only one element with the name 'name'
then use

```
document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value = getSavedValue("name");
```

Comment: there are more inputs like this and that didn't work properly

Comment: Can you post the entire code? so that we will be able to find out the issue