# How to pass data between redirect requests in Asp.net core while making sure the data is removed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tempdata

We've recently made a change where a process now needs the user to be logged in before they can finish it, but because there is complexity in changing the entry point, they can still start the process without being logged in.

So the flow is something like this:

1. User tries to do Step A
2. User is not logged in, so is redirected to Login (with their Step A data saved)
3. User logs in, and is redirected to finish Step A, with all their data

I'm trying to figure out the correct mechanism to use to keep that Step A data.
I tried using `TempData`, but the problem is that TempData seems to persist indefinitely if it is not consumed.

So, if the user doesn't complete the login in step 2, their tempdata is just sitting there forever, which is undesirable (maybe TempData works differently in production, but debugging locally, the unconsumed data in TempData survived a computer crash).

I would essentially like a way to store the data until it is consumed or the user has left the page, or ended the session.

EDIT (for comments): The data is not large, and is all string/int based, so I could put it into the database. Part of the data is essentially the controller/action that I need to redirect to after the login is done, plus parameters that are needed to be passed to it.  I'm not sure storing in the DB works though, since as you say, I would delete it after a set time. But if the user leaves and then comes back to the login page within that time, I don't want them to redirect, since that would cause confusion.

Hidden fields don't seem to me to solve the issue (I might be missing something). I have no issue getting the data to the original action, but I need to pass that data on to a different action.

Comment: according to me this concept is being used in almost every ECommerce platform as Guest Users. Insert an entry into DB and if User's doesn't register or not verifying the email, after some period of time you can delete the Data(can be done using scheduled tasks or something).

Comment: or if you really just want to achieve this without saving data into Database, you can always go for browser memory, Cookies etc.

Comment: Can you not just put the data in a hidden field?

Comment: @Alex, if the data will be more than 4-5 columns, then it can impact page rendering speed.

Comment: @RamSingh OP has not given any indication of how large the data is...or the type of data.

Comment: @Alex, i agree on it with you. even in that case, how can hidden field's data will be retrieved back after the page refresh? page will loose all the data from Hidden fields if  it is not being saved in backend somewhere. and Tempdata is being used to save and retrieve the data for next call. So for me using hidden field's in this situation is not going help.

Comment: @RamSingh You're right - the data would be lost on a page refresh...but from looking at the steps (1-3) outlined by OP, I didn't think that would be a concern...as they just wanted the values to be preserved after the redirect? But perhaps I haven't understood the issue here.

Comment: @kolichikov, so how the guest feature works, let me explain a bit here, whenever customer or user comes to your page, you are going to assign a record from DB to the current one, and whatever the past data you had got you have to assume that belongs to someone else and the current user is new customer for you. 

in this situation, there will not be any confusion along with the data.  if current session doesn't reach to sign up and redirect back to same page, means that data is useless for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256825/discussion-between-ram-singh-and-alex).

Comment: according to your description, I had a view in my mind which is similar to that, a user has  filled al the fields in the form but when he trys to click the submit button, the page redirect to the login site and after user signed in, the page redirect back to the form page and user could submit data this time. And your requirement is that you want to keep the data auto fill the fields when redirect back. Am I right? And in this scenario, I don't think it's good to store all these fields into database, as users might also give up submitting or modify the data,

Comment: if we store into db, we'll have a request to insert data and another request to read data, it might bring performance issue. Per my understand, since the data is up to the current user, I prefer to store data in the client side, for example localstorage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743862/save-data-to-local-storage

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to create a ReturnUrl string. So that once you use it is authorized - they are redirected to the action/page they were trying to perform/access prior to authorization.

- Go to you [HttpGet] `Login()`
- Add a `string ReturnUrl` as your parameter.
- Go to your LoginViewModel and add a nullable string property.

```
    // Example: 
    Public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
```

- Back to your `Login()` in the controller
- Create a model :

```
    // Example:
    var model = New LoginViewModel()
    {
        ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;
    }
    //Pass it to the View(model).
```

- Go to your view
- Inside your Form create a hidden input field to capture the ReturnUrl value. Which you will send to your [HttpPost] `Login()`.
- Inside your '*on successful login logic*' first check if ReturnUrl is not empty or null.

```
    // Example:
    if(/* You login condition check... */)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LoginViewModel.ReturnUrl))
        {
            return RedirectToPage(LoginViewModel.ReturnUrl);
        }
    };
```

Hope that helps!